# WebDriver Unable to Get Text from tbody List

Tags: selenium

Good afternoon people,

I'm trying to get all text from an element (list) on the webpage:

[image]

I tried the code below without success:

```
WebElement bodyText = driver0.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u_resultadochassi_case_table\"]"));                   
                    String Souce_code = bodyText.getAttribute("outerHTML");                 
                    System.out.println(Souce_code);
```

Basically I just need to get the info from:

**UF Gravame - 
Número - 
Data de Notificação - 
Chassi - 
Placa - 
Ofício - 
Data Liberação**

If I can get all text from the grid or outerHTML I can continue with the development

Attach the source code of the partial of the page:

```
<tbody class="list2_body"><tr id="row_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__YjIyNzY4NjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTY=-MDBlNjIwNjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5MTE=" class="list_row list_odd  list_row_compact" style="" sys_id="__ENC__YjIyNzY4NjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTY=-MDBlNjIwNjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5MTE=" record_class="u_resultadochassi_case" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case"><td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1"><span class="input-group-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" title="Marcar registro para Ação de lista" id="check_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__YjIyNzY4NjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTY=-MDBlNjIwNjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5MTE=" name="check_u_resultadochassi_case" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case" data-original-title="Marcar registro para Ação de lista"><label for="check_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__YjIyNzY4NjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTY=-MDBlNjIwNjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5MTE=" style="" class="checkbox-label"><span class="sr-only">Selecione o registro para ação: __ENC__YjIyNzY4NjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTY=-MDBlNjIwNjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5MTE=</span></label></span></td><td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1"><a href="u_resultadochassi_case.do?sys_id=__ENC__YjIyNzY4NjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTY=-MDBlNjIwNjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5MTE=&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=&amp;sysparm_record_row=1&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYresultado_u_data_liberacao&amp;sysparm_record_rows=1994" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case" style="margin-left:0px" title="" aria-label="Visualizar Registro: __ENC__YjIyNzY4NjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTY=-MDBlNjIwNjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5MTE=" data-use-href="true" data-popover-title="__ENC__YjIyNzY4NjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTY=-MDBlNjIwNjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5MTE=" data-popover-title-is-html="false" aria-haspop="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-original-title="Visualização __ENC__YjIyNzY4NjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTY=-MDBlNjIwNjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5MTE="></a></td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked formlink" aria-label="Abrir Registro: __ENC__YjIyNzY4NjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTY=-MDBlNjIwNjhkYjE5YTc4NGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5MTE=" href="sn_customerservice_resultado_chassis.do?sys_id=00e62068db19a784cd3d32ffaa961911&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=1&amp;sysparm_record_rows=1994&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYresultado_u_data_liberacao">MG</a></td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked formlink" aria-label="Abrir Registro:  __ENC__YTYwZTBlOGZkYjMwNjcwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5Mzg=-ODdkY2MyMGJkYjMwNjcwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ZjM=" href="task.do?sys_id=a60e0e8fdb30670472b47a30ba961938&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=49&amp;sysparm_record_rows=1994&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYresultado_u_data_liberacao">CS0391527</a></td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><div class="datex date-calendar" title="4 semanas atrás" timeago="2018-10-01 19:29:51" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="cerca de um mês atrás">01/10/2018 16:29:51</div><div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="4 semanas atrás" timeago="2018-10-01 19:29:51" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="cerca de um mês atrás">01/10 16:29</div><div class="datex date-timeago" title="01/10/2018 16:29:51" timeago="2018-10-01 19:29:51" data-original-title="01/10/2018 16:29:51" null="cerca de um mês atrás">cerca de um mês atrás</div></td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">9C2MC35006R043929</td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">HDY3415</td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">2316/2018</td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">00/00/0000 00:00:00</td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">Baixa Realizada</td><td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td></tr><tr id="row_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__YmVjMGMyNTFkYmMxMjc0NDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5YmM=-OGVjZmI5OTlkYjg5ZWYwNGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTI=" class="list_row list_even  list_row_compact" style="" sys_id="__ENC__YmVjMGMyNTFkYmMxMjc0NDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5YmM=-OGVjZmI5OTlkYjg5ZWYwNGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTI=" record_class="u_resultadochassi_case" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case"><td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1"><span class="input-group-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" title="Marcar registro para Ação de lista" id="check_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__YmVjMGMyNTFkYmMxMjc0NDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5YmM=-OGVjZmI5OTlkYjg5ZWYwNGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTI=" name="check_u_resultadochassi_case" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case" data-original-title="Marcar registro para Ação de lista"><label for="check_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__YmVjMGMyNTFkYmMxMjc0NDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5YmM=-OGVjZmI5OTlkYjg5ZWYwNGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTI=" style="" class="checkbox-label"><span class="sr-only">Selecione o registro para ação: __ENC__YmVjMGMyNTFkYmMxMjc0NDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5YmM=-OGVjZmI5OTlkYjg5ZWYwNGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTI=</span></label></span></td><td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1"><a href="u_resultadochassi_case.do?sys_id=__ENC__YmVjMGMyNTFkYmMxMjc0NDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5YmM=-OGVjZmI5OTlkYjg5ZWYwNGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTI=&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=50&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYresultado_u_data_liberacao&amp;sysparm_record_rows=1994" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case" style="margin-left:0px" title="Visualização __ENC__YmVjMGMyNTFkYmMxMjc0NDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5YmM=-OGVjZmI5OTlkYjg5ZWYwNGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTI=" aria-label="Visualizar Registro: __ENC__YmVjMGMyNTFkYmMxMjc0NDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5YmM=-OGVjZmI5OTlkYjg5ZWYwNGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTI=" data-use-href="true" data-popover-title="__ENC__YmVjMGMyNTFkYmMxMjc0NDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5YmM=-OGVjZmI5OTlkYjg5ZWYwNGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTI=" data-popover-title-is-html="false" aria-haspop="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-original-title="Visualização __ENC__YmVjMGMyNTFkYmMxMjc0NDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5YmM=-OGVjZmI5OTlkYjg5ZWYwNGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTI="></a></td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked formlink" aria-label="Abrir Registro: __ENC__YmVjMGMyNTFkYmMxMjc0NDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5YmM=-OGVjZmI5OTlkYjg5ZWYwNGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTI=" href="sn_customerservice_resultado_chassis.do?sys_id=8ecfb999db89ef04cd3d32ffaa961952&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=50&amp;sysparm_record_rows=1994&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYresultado_u_data_liberacao">MG</a></td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked formlink" aria-label="Abrir Registro: __ENC__YmVjMGMyNTFkYmMxMjc0NDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5YmM=-OGVjZmI5OTlkYjg5ZWYwNGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NTI=" href="task.do?sys_id=bec0c251dbc1274472b47a30ba9619bc&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=50&amp;sysparm_record_rows=1994&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYresultado_u_data_liberacao">CS0396337</a></td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><div class="datex date-calendar" title="3 semanas atrás" timeago="2018-10-08 19:44:07" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="28 dias atrás">08/10/2018 16:44:07</div><div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="3 semanas atrás" timeago="2018-10-08 19:44:07" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="28 dias atrás">08/10 16:44</div><div class="datex date-timeago" title="08/10/2018 16:44:07" timeago="2018-10-08 19:44:07" data-original-title="08/10/2018 16:44:07" null="28 dias atrás">28 dias atrás</div></td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">9C2KC2500HR028271</td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">PZA6261</td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">2479/2018</td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">00/00/0000 00:00:00</td><td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">Baixa Realizada</td><td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td></tr></tbody>
```

Comment: When you post HTML and/or code please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ or your IDE to properly format everything. If you need help properly formatting it on the site, see the formatting help link in the sidebar of the question editor. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Comment: For starters, your xPath is not getting you to to the actual td elements. Try the following xPath: `By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u_resultadochassi_case_table\"]/descendant::td[5]")` to get the 5th `td` element on that table

Comment: I try:    WebElement element2 = driver0.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u_resultadochassi_case_table\"]/descendant::td[5]")); But I could not locate the element

Comment: Thank you,

I was able to resolve after changing the focus of the driver to the frame where the grid is located!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was to change the focus of the Driver to the Frame where the Grid is located:

```
driver0.switchTo().frame("gsft_main");
WebElement PaginasGrid = driver0.findElement(By.id("list_nav_u_resultadochassi_case"));                     
System.out.println(totPaginas.getText());
```